# can you pass a current header to a route that you are redirecting to?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a route from authentication that does some authentications after it's done, it redirects to a protected route a route that need a JTW in order to be accessed the problem is my front end logic post the JWT authorization: 'Bearer' in to the authentication (/auth) middle ware then after the redirection happens the new rout doesn't get the JWT in order to let you access is there any way to pass the JWT further ? with the (res.redirect(`/app/:${id}`))

```js
//Sequence Express 
app.route('/signup')
    .post(authentication.signUp) // email password create JWT and send to FrontEnd  
app.route('/auth') 
    .post(authentication.auth) // varification gets JWT from FrontEnd    
app.route('/app/:id?')
    .get(authorization.barrier, toAppControler.getApp) // let you Accesse 
    
    
    
// Code 
exports.signUp = async (req, res, next) => {
    // sending the token to FE 
    res.cookie('JWT', token)
}

exports.auth = async (req, res, next) => {

   //Receive the token From 
   // redirect to app 
   res.redirect(`/app/:${id}`)
}
exports.barrier = async (req, res, next) => {
// the probelm is here how to pass the auth header to this route 
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')) {
        next()

    } else {
        res.sendStatus(403)

    }
}
```

in to the next middleware ?

Comment: You're setting the JWT as a cookie but then you try to read it from the authorization header... Why don't you try to read it from the cookie?

Comment: problem is I am doing a pin verifications for the email is existing ! so I have 2 forms one  sends first data and second send the pin I want to make use of the double posting and integrate authorization in to it but my knowledge gap in node is making things hard

Comment: You cannot set a custom header on a redirect that will come back to your server when the browser requests the redirected URL.  That's not how browsers do redirects.  They just make a  new empty request to the URL specified in the `location` header.  If the client was custom code, that that custom client could be taught to get headers off the 302 redirect response and attach them to the redirected request made from that same code, but a browser will not do that for you.  You can put data in cookies and those cookies will come back with the redirect (assuming same domain).

Comment: thanks for the info. so for my current implementation its better to use info from cookies then.